# How to access NodeJS server on LAN?

Tags: apache-http-server, node.js, networking, port, firewall

I'm not the most knowledgeable guy ever with networking, but here goes...

I've created an application with NodeJS and I'd like to test the application on my LAN with my family. The application listens on port `1337` for connections and I can access the application fine through my own PC by typing `localhost:1337`, `192.168.0.3:1337` or even `http://joel-pc:1337/` into my browser's address bar.

I will be also be running apache alongside NodeJS, and I can access this fine by typing `192.168.0.3` or `http://joel-pc/` into a browser's address bar as long as it's connected to the same network.

Now here's the weird part; If I stop the apache service, change my node application to listen on port `80` (http) insted of `1337`, it will be accessible on my pc by typing `localhost`, `192.168.0.3` or even `http://joel-pc` into my browser's address bar. However, I still can't access NodeJS on any other PC on my network apart from my own.

I've tried creating an outbound rule within Windows 7 to allow access to port 1337, but I still can't get access to my NodeJS server on any other PC than my own, even if it's listening on port 80. Is there something obvious I'm missing out on here?

Comment: What if, as a test only, you turn off your firewall?

Comment: If I turn off my firewall I can access node perfectly, thank you :) But surely there must be a safer way of doing things?

Comment: I've put it back on now, don't worry :) Should I post on there too? Or is there a way of moving my question over? thank you

Comment: I have flagged your question saying it belongs to superuser. Not sure how long it will take but it should work!

Comment: Cheers. I flagged it too because I read in another thread that it needs to be flagged by 3 users before any action is taken by a moderator

Comment: Still not moved over? Where are the mods lol? :(

Comment: The flag I raised has been deemed helpful, so not sure how long it can take!

Comment: When you ran the server for the first time, didn't the firewall ask you to allow the program to run through or not?

Comment: If you are on windows, you may need to allow the connection through [Windows Firewall](https://coderwall.com/p/mbov6w/running-nodejs-and-express-on-windows)

Comment: This is a normal problem and usually involves allowing incoming connections to node.exe for the desired network types. On a laptop I wouldn't recommend enabling it for public networks, so you can have a little extra safety on public wifi, though you still need to set the network as a public network to make use of this.

Comment: On which default port is `npm install` making its connexion?

Answer (score 15):

Most likely your node application is binding to the loopback IP address `127.0.0.1` instead of the "all IPs" `0.0.0.0` since this is the default behavior of `listen`. Specify both port and IP in your call like `server.listen(80, '0.0.0.0');` and try again.

Comment: If I do this, I still can't access Node on any other device on my LAN. My code looks something like this:var io = require('socket.io');
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var server = require('http').createServer(app)
io = io.listen('80', '0.0.0.0');

Comment: This worked in my case. On some wireless networks `localhost` works as a string, but in others you have to type it as `127.0.0.1`

Comment: This is incorrect in light of the question as currently written, because it can in fact be accessed on the local computer using the LAN address, which means it is listening on that address as well.

Answer (score 6):

Get you current local network IP and, run http server like this:

```
server.listen(80, 'current_local_ip');
```

Comment: this works for me.

Comment: The NodeJS docs state that if no IP is specified it will listen on wildcard (in order: `::` or `0.0.0.0`)

Answer (score 5):

Doing following worked for me on a windows PC.
Try this : open

> **Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Defender Firewall\Allowed
>   apps**

Next look for node.js in the list and click change settings > Make sure private access is checked and then click ok.

Comment: mine was working before, and somehow it was disabled in windows firewall, this fixed my issue, thanks

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to add `C:\Program Files (x86)\node` to the list of trusted applications in your firewall.

Then, in your node app, you can write:

```
listen(3333, '172.24.14.26', function() {
```

or:

```
listen(3333, '0.0.0.0', function() {
```

or:

```
listen(3333, function() {
```

or:

```
listen(80, '172.24.14.26', function() {
```

or:

```
listen(80, '0.0.0.0', function() {
```

or:

```
listen(80, function() {
```

Each one of these 6 combinations work in my case: node.js on Windows Server 2016, protected by a company proxy.

Answer (score 4):

I found a good solution for this problem. Rather than doing all the configurations (Setting firewall, forwarding port etc) I used **localtunnel** which is an utility for exposing local node server over Internet. You can use it for development,testing,sharing purpose, just don't use it for production.

First you have to install localtunnel as follows:

```
$npm install -g localtunnel
```

After that configure your node app such that your node server should be running on localhost.
For ex:

```
server.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('Listening to port:  ' + port);
});
```

Note down **your_port** which in my case was **3000**, and start your node server.

Open another terminal and type following command for running localtunnel.

```
$lt --port 3000
```

After this , in terminal you will get an URL which you can use it for development/testing purpose. This URL will be available on Internet so you can share it with others too. As long as your localtunnel is running, others can access your local node server.

For more configuration options/help you can go through documentation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/localtunnel